# How to search data from multiple tables without using JOIN?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

At first, I'm apologize for my bad English

I got two input and two table

I want search `table2` data but only get `table1` value

the reason I don't wanna use join is using join will make me can't use foreign key in view

like `<p>{{$table1->table2->name}}</p>` and cause table1 got more relate table

so I can't easily change to

```
<p>{{$table1->name}}</p>
```

I have try

```
tables2 = table2::all()->where('table2_column', 'like', '%' . request('input2') . '%')->get();

foreach($tables2 as table2){
tables1 = table1::all()->where('table1_column', 'like', '%' . request('input') . '%')
                       ->where('table2_id','=',$table2->id)table->get();
}
```

but it doesn't work. Is there have any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#additional-where-clauses)

```php
$table1_id = table1::where('table1_column', 'like', '%' . request('input1') . '%')->pluck('id');
$table2=table2::where('table2_column', 'like', '%' . request('input2') . '%')->whereIn('table1_id',$table1_id)->get();
```